# What's the best semantic way of having a break in a ul-based navbar?

Tags: css, xhtml, semantics

I'm making a ul-based horizontal navbar, but I want to have two levels heading in each item, a bit like this:

```
     Nav item1            Nav item2             Nav item3
Nav item1 subtitle    Nav item2 subtitle    Nav item3 subtitle
```

The subtitle has to be in a different style to the main nav item.
I did this first (naively?) by using a p nested inside the li, but [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/) said I couldn't nest a p inside an li.

Basically, I'm trying to avoid a br, mainly because that's not proper semantics is it? Am I going about this the wrong way?

EDIT: I should have added, I want the nav item and it's subtitle in the same anchor tag, because they are one link (and I want a:hover to work). This precludes the use of multiple heading tags within the li I think.

EDIT 2: The answers were useful, thanks. An interesting thing to note - although it was said that block span == div, that's not the way the W3C validator sees it. You can always have a span nested inside an anchor, even if the span's display:block, but you can't e.g. have a display:inline h1 inside an anchor, because the validator doesn't check the CSS and HTML files together.

Comment: You could always include the heading tags inside of the anchor and set them to display:inline. I think, as others have suggested, using a <span> is the way to go, though.

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? p inside li seems perfectly valid to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `span` since that's semantically inert, then style it with `display: block`.

Comment: I would personally recommend an <em>, since "semantically inert" isn't always a good thing, especially if there's actual semantical difference.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that `<br />` is semantically appropriate for a line break separating a title and subtitle. You can style it differently using a `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary list instead of a regular unordered list. Your example should be.

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    Nav Item 1
  </dt>
  <dd>
    Nav Item 1 Subtitle
  </dd>
  <dt>
    Nav Item 2
  </dt>
  <dd>
    Nav Item 2 Subtitle
  </dd>
  <dt>
    Nav Item 2
  </dt>
  <dd>
    Nav Item 2 Subtitle
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Or in HTML5 or XHTML 2.0 You can do

```
<dl>
  <di>
    <dt>
      Nav Item 1
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Nav Item 1 Subtitle
    </dd>
  </di>
  <di>
    <dt>
      Nav Item 2
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Nav Item 2 Subtitle
    </dd>
  </di>
  <di>
    <dt>
      Nav Item 2
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Nav Item 2 Subtitle
    </dd>
  </di>
</dl>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Span with display: block==div
2. <li>
             <h3>title </h3>
             <h4>sub title </h4>
    </li>

(Or any of the other possible H tags.

Comment: This works, although only if I don't enclose the entire contents of the li in an "a" tag, which is a bummer because I have a hover css effect on the link...

Comment: Give the [a] display: block and then do it.

Comment: The validator will still treat it as an inline element though.